# Angular/cli and HTTP 404 for local content

Tags: json, angular-cli

Up until @angular/cli 1.0.1 I was able to serve up test data from a local JSON file just by supplying the relative patch to the http component. For example,
*this.http.get(''/src/app/testdata/sopData.json'').map(...)*, would happily serve up the JSON from the root of the ng4 project.    After upgrading to 1.0.1 this no longer works. I get a 404 on the http://localhost:4200/src/app/testdata/sopData.json request.

If I down grade to 1.0.0 it serves up the fine without error.  I never really understood how not specifying a server translated to a straight file operation but I did take advantage of it.  The fact that it doesn't work anymore doesn't feel like a bug, it feels more like a loophole that's been closed.  Anyone have insight?

Comment: is the given solutions are solve your problem

Answer (score 3):

Open `angular-cli.json` and add folder name into assets array, like

```
  "assets": [
    "assets",
    "favicon.ico",
    "testdata"
  ],
```

Answer (score 0):

After upgrading this morning I was experiencing the same problem. To correct the issue I moved my files into the assets folder and changed the code references. Everything works now.

Prior to that I tried adding my "data" folder to the apps/assets object in my .angular-cli.json, but that didn't appear to resolve the issue.